# Syntax error when reading a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

The code is meant to take a file as input, change all the letters to lowercase and get rid of any non alphabetical characters. Then it should print out the recurrence of each word in the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import sys

def main(argv):
    try:    
        tf = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
    except IOError:
        print("The file ",tf," was not found")
        sys.exit() 
data = tf.read()
data.lower()
data.replace("-"," ")
validLetters = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
cleanData = ''.join([i for i in data if i in validLetters])
frequency = {}
words = []
words = cleanData.split()
for x in words:
    if frequency.has_key(x):
        frequency[x] = frequency[x] + 1
    else:
        frequency[x]
print sorted(frequency.values())
tf.close()
```

this is what I get in the command line:

```
$ python -m py_compile q1_word_count.py drake.txt
  File "drake.txt", line 1
I Was A Teenage Hacker
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

"I Was A Teenage Hacker" is the first line of the text file..

Comment: just run it like this `python q1_word_count.py drake.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Your script is probably all right, but you're running it in an incorrect way.

You're enabling the `py_compile` module

> The py_compile module provides a function to generate a byte-code file from a source file

The module takes all arguments from command line, including your text file, and finds syntax errors in it obviously.

just run it like this:

```
python q1_word_count.py drake.txt
```

(you can compile your module first: `python -m py_compile q1_word_count.py`, in which case you can run the `.pyc` generated bytecode file, and changing your `.py` file would need a recompilation everytime for a very tiny speed gain at startup, and none when executing, this is bytecode compilation, not dynamic compilation. If you want dynamic compilation, use `pypy`)